# PHP array issue - Undefined offset

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

I have an array defined as such:

```
<?php $Invoices = array();
foreach ($bookings as $booking){
    $Invoices[$booking['id'] = $booking['invoice_no']];
}
?>
```

However, I'm getting a `Notice (8): Undefined offset error`.

Currently, all `$booking['id']` are identical to `$booking['invoice_no']` - that will change; they're just test values for now (otherwise I would just stick to using `$bookings`).

I plan to use the array for options in a form input:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <?= $this->Form->input('booking_id', ['class' => 'form-control',
    'label' => 'Invoice Number', 'id' => 'booking_id', 'options' => 
    $Invoices]); ?>
</div>
```

Checking my CakePHP 3 debugger, `$bookings` definitely has sub arrays with elements - for example, `$bookings[0]['id']` = `$bookings[0]['invoice_no']` = 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bad syntax here: `$Invoices[$booking['id'] = $booking['invoice_no']];`

Should be:

```
$Invoices[$booking['id']] = $booking['invoice_no'];
```

Comment: Thanks, overlooked that - editor didn't catch it either.

Comment: @mistaq if you solve by using this solution, then you should accept this answer

Comment: Sorry, the answer was submitted quickly, so when I wanted to accept it, it said I had to wait a few minutes. It's done now.